# ISP Search Parameter in resolve.conf

Tags: dhcp, kubernetes, systemd-resolved

I will try to explain this right, not a linux guru!  About a week ago suddenly started getting a 401 when sending requests, seems that on our kubernetes cluster when it hits the one node that has a DHCP reserved address it fails.

I can see from the logs.

```
2024-03-03T01:54:50.100648572Z [ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 mq.my-dev.webpass.net. A: read udp 10.0.0.123:58924->8.8.4.4:53: i/o timeout
```

I can see the resolve.conf has the line:

```
search webpass.net
```

Webpass is our ISP.  The kubernetes cluster has been working fine for a year, then all of a sudden this started 2 weeks ago.  Please note our kubernetes is installed on bare metal.

I have been advised just need to comment out the line search webpass.net, but this file is generated don't know where to look to find the source of where this is coming from.  Cannot see anything obvious in the router and nothing has changed in a long time.

Comment: What is your operating system? Are you using other DNS related services like systemd-resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

I was able to exec into the pod of the application and found that it had copied the `webpass.net` to the search parameter in the `resolve.conf` on one pod only, so it failed when it hit that pod.

I removed it from the `resolve.conf` in the k8 pod, and I also removed it from the `resolve.conf` on Ubuntu so it doesn't copy over again, by breaking the symlink and modifying the file directly.  I'm sure there is probably a more elegant way of fixing it using NetworkManager.